# How to communicate via com port with jSerialComm using CP210 driver

Tags: java, javafx, serial-port, com-port

I have Silicon Labs CP210 driver to communicate with com port device. The problem is that I am not able to read data from com port device with cp210 driver. The library I have use is [`jSerialComm`](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm) in a JavaFX project.

I have written below code to connect, write, and read with com port device, but I am not able read data.

```
  SerialPort _serialPort;
        SerialPort[] ports;
        ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
        _serialPort = SerialPort.getCommPort(ports[0].getSystemPortName());
        System.out.println(ports[0].getSystemPortName());
        _serialPort.setBaudRate(19200);
        _serialPort.setNumDataBits(8);
        _serialPort.setNumStopBits(1);
        _serialPort.setParity(SerialPort.NO_PARITY);
        _serialPort.setDTR();
        _serialPort.setRTS();
        _serialPort.openPort();
        _serialPort.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_BLOCKING, 4000, 4000);
//        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        String hexValue = "CC"; // Example hex value
        byte[] hexBytes = hexStringToByteArray(hexValue);
        _serialPort.writeBytes(hexBytes, 2);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1 / 3);
        String hexValue2 = "AB"; // Example hex value
        byte[] hexBytes2 = hexStringToByteArray(hexValue2);
        _serialPort.writeBytes(hexBytes2, 2);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1 / 3);
        String hexValue3 = "AB"; // Example hex value
        byte[] hexBytes3 = hexStringToByteArray(hexValue3);
        _serialPort.writeBytes(hexBytes3, 2);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

        if (_serialPort.bytesAvailable() == -1) {
//                Portname=null;
            _serialPort.closePort();
            return;
        }

        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[_serialPort.bytesAvailable()];
        long read12 = _serialPort.readBytes(readBuffer, readBuffer.length);
        String response = new String(readBuffer).trim();
        System.out.println("res  " + response);
        System.out.println(readBuffer.length);
        String[] response1 = response.split(",");
        welcomeText.setText("Read " + response + " bytes.");
        if (response1[0].equals("BLE_READER")) {
            String[] ab = response.split(",");
            System.out.println("yess logger1  "+ Arrays.toString(ab));
        } else {
            _serialPort.closePort();
//                openporttittle.setText("Open Port : ");
        }
```

If there any problem in my code ,then please update me.

Comment: Note this does not seem to have anything to do with JavaFX. That framework is not involved in reading COMs. Including it in the problem only complicates the issue. You need to think about getting your COM code to work in isolation. I recommend you [edit] your question to remove the [tag:javafx] tag and provide the error(s) you're getting, along with a proper [mre]—without JavaFX—demonstrating the error(s). You should also better describe what you expected to happen versus what is actually happening. Read [ask] for more information.

Comment: The project's [wiki](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/wiki) illustrates several use cases that may be helpful in the context of a JavaFX `Task` or `Service`.

Comment: After you fix your IO issue, ensure that the IO (and those sleep calls you have) are not performed on the JavaFX thread (probably instead using the tools referenced in Trashgod’s comment).